# Rails 4 has_many :through : display child attribute in parent model index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, has-many-through, join

I have three models, with a has_many :through association :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

The join Administration model has the following attributes:

```
id
user_id
calendar_id
role
```

And here is my `Calendars#Index`:

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @calendars = Calendar.all
end
```

Currently, here is what is in my Calendar index view:

```
<tbody>
  <% @calendars.each do |calendar| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to calendar.name, user_calendar_path(@user.id, calendar.id) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user_calendar_path(@user, calendar), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Now, right after each calendar name, still in the Calendar index view, I would like to display the role of the current user for this calendar.

To do so, I need to get the information from the `administrations` join table, where `user_id = current_user.id` (or `@user.id`) and `calendar_id = calendar.id`.

I tried different solutions, but kept running into `NoMethodError`s and `NameError`s.

————————

**UPDATE:**

Below are the different solutions I tried.

*Solution 1*

Add `<td><%= calendar.administration.role %></td>` in Calendar index view.

Returned:

```
NoMethodError in Calendars#index
undefined method `administration' for #<Calendar:0x007f88fb88a050>
```

*Solution 2*

Add `<td><%= calendar.administrations.role %></td>` in Calendar index view.

Returned:

```
NoMethodError in Calendars#index
undefined method `role' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

*Solution 3*

Add `<td><%= calendar.role %></td>` in Calendar index view.

Returned:

```
NoMethodError in Calendars#index
undefined method `role' for #<Calendar:0x007f88faf66a78>
```

————————

How can I make this work?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on how the calendars, users, and administrations are related to each other?

Comment: Sure. In my question, you can already find the details of the `has_many :through` association and the fields of the `administrations` table, which is the join table between the `users` table and the `calendars` table. What else would be of help? I am happy to update my question with additional elements.

Comment: @ThibaudClement please try my answer. It should give you the desried role :)

Comment: Check out enum for Rails 4. This is a great new tool in Rails 4 that allows you to assign and access roles/statuses/etc very easily. [http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html]

Comment: Your Solution 1 does not work because it's referencing a singular administration when you have a `has_many` relationship, so it should be plural, like what you tried in Solution 2. But Solution 2 won't work because `calendar.administrations.role` is trying to retrieve a *single* role from a collection of administrations, so then Rails flips out and is all like "Yo, bro, I have No Method for that." And your Solution 3 is looking for a role from within the Calendar table, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, it makes sense.

Comment: No problem! Definitely check out the link I put in the comment above about creating roles with  `Enum`. It has saved my life countless times when I've built my Rails apps!

Comment: Sure. Just FYI, the link return a 404 error page because of the final square bracket. Maybe you could update it in your comment so other people can follow it too ;) Again, thanks a lot for your time and your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the `role` from the `Administration` model directly from your view like this because you already have access to `@user` and `calendar` in your view:

```
Administration.where(user_id: @user.id, calendar_id: calendar.id).first.try(:role)
```

Comment: Thanks for your responsiveness. The code you suggest returns the following error: `NoMethodError in Calendars#index undefined method `role' for nil:NilClass`. Should I add some validation or is the problem coming from somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

A calendar has many administrations, one for each user. You need to find the one associated with your specific user. Finding that can be done like this

`calendar.administrations.where(user_id: @user.id)`

or

`calendar.administrations.select{|administration| administration.user_id = @user.id}`

Now, these return a list, not an individual item, so you'll want to grab the first one:

`calendar.administrations.where(user_id: @user.id).first`

You now have the first Administration object for the given user. You can then ask for the role.

Try this as a solution.

`<%= calendar.administrations.where(user_id: @user.id).first.role %>`

Comment: Yep, this solution works too ;) Thank you very much.